# org-agenda stuck displaying last file in org-agenda-files list

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, debugging

For some reason, (after recently upgrading packages), running `org-agenda` via `C-c a` and then selecting a view from the dispatch buffer (such as `a Agenda for current week or day`) just shows me a buffer with the last file in my `org-agenda-files` list - in this case, an org file called `work-notebook.org`.

Looking at the buffer list, I can find the `*Org Agenda*` buffer listed and so can switch with `C-x C-b`, but is there any way I can restore the usual behavior -- i.e. the `*Org Agenda*` buffer opens in a window in my current frame?

I usually have `org-agenda-window-setup` set at `current-window`, changing it to `reorganize-frame` still gives me the same problem.

I'm running `Emacs 27.2` using `Org mode version 9.4.4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used `bug-hunter` as recommended on the [emacs subbreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/w8w6xl/orgagenda_stuck_displaying_last_file_in/). Took a while to set up as I have a literate configuration and a couple of other bugs popped up. But after copying everything to a new `.el` file and running `bug-hunter-file` on it, the issue was isolated to `org-gcal`, and in particular to the line in my config

```
(add-hook 'org-save-all-org-buffers (lambda () (org-gcal-sync) ))
```

It turns out there is now a bug in `org-gcal-fetch` (which affects `org-gcal-sync`) that ["forces org files into active window"](https://github.com/kidd/org-gcal.el/issues/202). This leads to a one-line fix that solves the issue (changing `switch-to-buffer` to `set-buffer` in `org-generic-id.el`).